# Load files needed by a namespace (with a different name)?

Tags: php, class, namespaces

I have two files as described below:

**Path: index.php**

```
<?php
// Composer autload
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

//The commented code below works:
//$loader = new Twig_Loader_String();
//$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
//echo $twig->render('Hello {{ name }}!', array('name' => 'Fabien'));

//Bad proposal solution. How to avoid to explicit load all files with namespaces?
//  Please see the 'Important edit' below.
//include_once 'Core/Twig/Twig.php';
use Core\Twig\Twig as Twig;

$twig = new Twig();
var_dump($twig);
```

**Path: Core/Twig/Twig.php**

```
<?php
namespace Core\Twig;

class Twig
{
    public function configure()
    {
        $loader = new \Twig_Loader_String();
        $twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);
        //just for testing
        echo $twig->render('Hello {{ name }}!', array('name' => 'Fabien'));
    }
}
```

But I'm getting a fatal error: `Class 'Core\\Twig\\Twig' not found`.

How can I solve this?

P.S.: I'd tried some variations to the namespace (like `Core\Twig`, `Core`), use (like `Twig`, `Core\Twig`, `Core\Twig as Twig`) and new (like `Twig\Twig()`, `Core\Twig`). Unfortunally, nothing works.

**Important edit:**
I'd understand why php was not locating the class. A line like `include_once 'Core/Twig/Twig.php'` was needed. But the problem still continues... how can I avoid this? Avoid to include all files with namespaces? Or, how can I autoload this files when it are needed?

Comment: What does `autoload.php` look like?

Comment: autoload is the composer autload. It enables Twig. Twig is working, but I couldnt let it work with the namespace.

Comment: I'm new to namespaces as well, but have you tried `use lib\vendor\core\Twiggy as MyNamespace` and `namespace lib\vendor\core\Twiggy`? Seems to me like you might be having a clash between the class name and the namespace. `use lib\vendor\core\Twig as Twig` reads in the namespace, not the actual class - that's my understanding anyway.

Comment: Funny question, what's your version of PHP?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, ˆˆ The complete version is: PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug 24 2012 17:45:44)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

Comment: I use another machine with `PHP 5.4.13-2~precise+1 (cli) (built: Mar 21 2013 12:17:18) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several testings I'd reached the answer. Inspecting the `vendor/autoload.php`.

We need something not explicit (at least to me).

On the `composer.json` we need to put

```
psr-0 : {
    "MyNamespace" : "MyOwnVendorName"
}
```

to this case, the following code should run:

`Path: index.php`

```
<?php
// Composer autload
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use classes\MyApp\Twig\Twig;

$twig = new Twig;
var_dump($twig);
```

`Path: core/classes/MyApp/Twig/Twig.php`

```
<?php
namespace MyApp\Twig;

class Twig
{
    public function configure()
    {
        $loader = new \Twig_Loader_String();
        $twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);
        //just for testing
        echo $twig->render('Hello {{ name }}!', array('name' => 'Fabien'));
    }
}
```

`composer.json`

```
{
    "psr-0" : {
        "MyApp" : "core/classes/"
    }
}
```

then run `php composer.phar udpate`

Answer (score 2):

You may be marking the namespace incorrectly. Check out the "Namespace importing: the use keyword" section [in this namespace primer.](http://akrabat.com/php/a-primer-on-php-namespaces/)

**Path: lib/vendor/core/Twig.php**

```
<?php
namespace lib\vendor\core;

class Twig
{
    //Your code
}
```

**Path: index.php**

```
use lib\vendor\core\Twig;
$twig = new Twig();
var_dump($twig);
```

Comment: thx for help. Unfortunally this solution didn't work. Very strange. For example ctrl+click on Netbeans redirects to the class declaration, but I'm getting fatal error `class not found`. =/

Comment: John, I have change the directories. Looks like now is the standard.

Comment: @GarouDan Are you saying you've applied my suggestion exactly as my code suggests? Is it working?

Comment: Yes, I tried to apply exactly your solution. But didn't worked. After this I changed the directories to the standard.

Comment: @GarouDan If you've changed the directories to the standard, please update your code in the question, it will make it less confusing. Unfortunately I don't have another answer for you at the moment, but updating your code in your question might help others figure out the problem.

Comment: I've already changed^^ see `Core/Twig/Twig.php` is different from `lib/vendor/Twig.php`. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @GarouDan You still aren't implementing it as I suggested. Make the namespace just `namespace core` - no "\Twig" after it. So then it would be `use core\Twig` - don't do "as Twig" after it.